# Nhibernate Icriteria Enum flags (BitMask) support

Tags: nhibernate

[Flags]

```
public enum ShowProductOn : short

{

    HomePage = 1,

    SalesPage = 2,

    NewsLetter = 4

};
```

Valid values for this enum:

1 - HomePage

2 - SalesPage

3 - HomePage, SalesPage

4 - NewsLetter

5 - HomePage, NewsLetter

6 - SalesPage, NewsLetter

7 - HomePage, SalesPage, NewsLetter

I would like to write a criteria that returns all the products on homepage.
To check it in c# is very simple:

if ((MY_PARAM & ShowProductOn.HomePage) == ShowProductOn.HomePage)

```
Console.WriteLine("Yes");
```

in Sql it's also very simple:

DECLARE @BitMask int = 3

IF ((@BitMask & 1) = 1)

BEGIN

```
Print('Yes')
```

END

This is the NH Criteria that I wrote to return all products on homepage (should match 1|3|5|7):

ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ShowProductOn", ShowProductOn.HomePage));

This criteria  returns only items with "ShowProductOn"=1 but ignores the other matched items with "ShowProductOn"=3|5|7.

Does anyone knows the ICriteria /HQL syntax to write a criteria that will return all items with "ShowProductOn"=1|3|5|7 ?

Shay.

Answer (score 3):

this might be useful.

[How to query flags stored as enum in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805661/how-to-query-flags-stored-as-enum-in-nhibernate/2806876#2806876)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this one mapping the flag enum to a string type, then using Restrictions.Like for quering values:

Property definition:

```
public virtual DaysOfWeek Weekdays {
  get { return (DaysOfWeek)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), _weekdays); }
  set { _weekdays = value.ToString(); }
}
private string _weekdays = "All";
```

Property mapping (using hbm.xml file)

```
<property name="Weekdays" column="WEEKDAYS" access="field.camelcase-underscore" not-null="false" />
```

And finally the criteria query:

```
Restrictions.Like("Weekdays", ConvertToDaysOfWeek(time.DayOfWeek).ToString(), MatchMode.Anywhere);
```

Hope this helps.