# How can I specify a bitmask/bitfield WHERE clause using NHibernate's Criterion API

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, bit-fields, nhibernate-criteria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to query flags stored as enum in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805661/how-to-query-flags-stored-as-enum-in-nhibernate)

I have three tables - `Recipient`, `Message`, `MessageType`

MessageType looks like this:

```
| ID | Description  |
|====|==============|
|  1 | JobAlert     |
|  2 | Newsletter   |
|  3 | SpecialOffer |
|  4 | Survey       |
```

`Recipient` contains an integer column which is used as a bitfield; recipients can choose what types of message they want to receive; If a recipient wants to receive newsletters and special offers, we'll set their bitfield to `(2 ^ 2) | (2 ^ 3)`

`Message` contains a reference to `MessageTypeId`, and computed column `MessageTypeBitFlag` which is defined as `POWER(2, MessageTypeId)`

My query expressed in SQL looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Message, Recipient
  WHERE Recipient.MessageTypeBitField & Message.MessageTypeBitFlag > 0
```

by doing a bitwise-AND on the bitfield and bitflag columns, it's easy to select only the messages that a particular recipient is interested in.

Problem is, I'm not doing this in SQL - I need to add this as an additional option to a fairly rich system built on the NHibernate Criteria API.

Is there any way to express this criteria via the NHibernate API - either using the API or by adding an SQL/HQL clause to the existing criteria?

Comment: I know this is completely orthogonal to your question so feel free to disregard.  Do you really need to use bit flags?  Obviously creating separate columns for the different types would solve your ORM problem and on the DB side its the same amount of disk storage either way.  You could expose a synthetic field on your biz object so if users of your object wanted to read/write the bitflag variable then you just translate it behind the scenes into the SQL fields. I think it makes your model easier to understand instead of having to remember what, for instance, bit 7 stands for.

Comment: The big advantage of using bitfields is that, as long as your IDs are bounded, you can add additional message types without requiring any schema changes. Sure, we could achieve the same using many-many link tables, but this approach is much more lightweight.

Comment: see answere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5989231/671619)

Comment: Yep - that's it. Voted to close as duplicate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a specific implementation based on [this linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989231/671619) submitted by [Firo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671619/firo), because I had to adapt this a little to make it work:

```
/// <summary>An NHibernate criterion that does bitwise comparison to match a bit flag against a bitmask.</summary>
public class BitMask : LogicalExpression {
    private BitMask(string propertyName, object value, string op) :
        base(new SimpleExpression(propertyName, value, op), Expression.Sql("?", 0, NHibernateUtil.Int64)) {
    }

    protected override string Op {
        get { return ">"; }
    }
    /// <summary>Create a bitwise filter criterion - i.e. one that will be satisified if <code><paramref name="propertyName"/> &amp; <paramref name="bits"/> &gt; 0</code></summary>
    public static BitMask Matches(string propertyName, long bits) {
        return new BitMask(propertyName, bits, " & ");
    }
}
```

and then use it via the Criteria API as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesForRecipient(Recipient r) {
    var messages = session.CreateCriteria<Message>()
        .Add(BitMask.Matches("MessageTypeBitFlag ", r.MessageTypeBitField))
        .List<Message>();
    return(messages);
}
```