# Using a native SQL Server function in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, nhibernate

I'm building a WPF application that queries a database through Nhibernate.

I have a SQL Server database with a table `xuser` where there is a flag (`xflag`) that stores the user's permissions.

Now I have this SQL query to extract superuser or administrators:

```
select * 
from xuser 
where (CONVERT(int,xflag) & 2 > 0 ) or (CONVERT(int,xflag) & 1 > 0 )
```

where `2 = flag_administrators` and `1 = flag_superusers`

Without the SQL function `CONVERT`, this query doesn't work with error:

> *The data types numeric and int are incompatible in the '&' operator.*

Now in my WPF c# nhibnernate app, I query with:

```
var xadmins= session.Query<Xuser>()
                    .Where(p => (p.Xflag & (int)Flag.FLAG_SUPERUSER)>0).ToList<string>();
```

This query doesn't work with the same SQL error.

I want to use T-SQL function in this Linq2Nhibernate query. How can I do that?

The big problem is that this application have to works with `MsSql2008` or `Oracle` dialect. If I use `Convert` function here, when I'll change db to `Oracle`, this function go to error. What is the best pratices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the mapping for xflag as a formula so it is converted to an int, i.e.

```
<property name="Xflag" formula="CONVERT(int,xflag)"/>
```

Or for Fluent NHibernate

```
Map(x => x.Xflag).Formula("CONVERT(int,xflag)");
```

You can then use your expression to get all super users without the cast:

```
var xadmins= session.Query<Xuser>()
                .Where(p => (p.Xflag & Flag.FLAG_SUPERUSER)>0).ToList<string>();
```

Of course this has the disadvantage of being SQL Server specific. For this to work for Oracle you would need to use the mapping:

```
<property name="Xflag" formula="to_number(xflag)"/>
```

To get around this issue to could create a User Defined Function in both DBs that would perform the conversion so the mapping would then become:

```
<property name="Xflag" formula="xflag_conversion(xflag)"/>
```

With the Oracle UDF being something like the following.

```
CREATE FUNCTION xflag_conversion(xflag IN CHAR) 
  RETURN NUMBER 
   BEGIN  
  RETURN(to_number(xflag)); 
END;
```

The SQL Server UDF would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION xflag_conversion (@xflag CHAR)
  RETURNS INT
  AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(int,xflag)
  END
```

No guarantees about the accuracy of the UDFs though, as I have not tested them.

Finally here is an related question about querying flag information which may be of interest to you: [How to query flags stored as enum in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805661/how-to-query-flags-stored-as-enum-in-nhibernate/5989231#5989231).